# javascript prototype with a jquery in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am defining a javascript prototype with a function that has a jquery selector in it. An over simplified version of my code can be found below:

```
function MyObj(id1){
this.id1 = id1;
}
MyObj.prototype.MyFunc = function(id2){
$('#' + this.id1).val(id2)
}
var newObj = new MyObj("id1_val");
```

I cannot use this in MyFunc, because this is the `context` (as perseved by JQuery), Is there a way to access the value of id1? Is it even possible to have a prototype with a function that has jquery in it?

I do need to maintain access to the context, because the code is part of a form submission and I have `$(this).submit();`

---

EDIT:
I have a function

```
bar(id2){
 var newObj = new MyObj("id1_val");
 Foo(id2, newObj.MyFunc)
}
```

bar is being called in `fuction start() {bar}; window.onload = start;`

Comment: `this` in your code refers to the context, not to `window`.

Comment: You are right, I will update the question

Comment: What do you mean ? if you `alert(this.id1)` you will get the value of `id1`

Comment: Now, how are you calling `MyFunc`? If you're doing `newObj.MyFunc(...)` the code works as expected.

Comment: @Teemu That's what i've written also

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yep, jQuery doesn't have any affect to `this` value here. Ahaa, it appears that it's executed as a callback ...